# Strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, primitive

I have recently seen some references that explain Strings in Javascript as a primitive type.I know that a primitive is a data type that is composed of no other data types and can not be broken down any further.But the problem is I have also read strings are objects.How it can be both ?Please clarify me about the confusion.

Comment: A number of built-in types like String, Date, Array and also objects that have methods or may be automatically converted to objects as needed.  Why is this hard to believe or understand?

Comment: Go to your browser's console and type `typeof new String("s")` and also `typeof "asfd"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about that exact topic on MDN:

> Note that JavaScript distinguishes between String objects and
>   primitive string values. (The same is true of booleans and numbers.)
>
> String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings
>   returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without
>   using the new keyword) are primitive strings. JavaScript automatically
>   converts primitives to String objects, so that it's possible to use
>   String object methods for primitive strings. In contexts where a
>   method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup
>   occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and
>   call the method or perform the property lookup.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: Sorry,I'm new to SO,cant upvote the answer.(min 15 reputation).I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @vetexion No problem. There's an outline of a check mark near the upvote button and if you click it, it should turn green. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91889/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-to-my-questions?lq=1